# Aplicar css solo a un div en html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Me preguntaba si se puede aplicar un css a un solo div en mi web page,
he tenido varios problemas con aplicar css a mi web page, no tengo la mínima  idea de como poder aplicar esto.

Lo que pasa es que tengo un css de Bootstrap y otro "mio" y "chocan" entonces quisiera aplicar el css de Bootstrap a un div en especifico y el otro css a otro div y que no tenga problema alguno.

espero me puedan ayudar! saludos.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes mediante reglas CSS, asignarle un identificador o una clase es lo más recomendado.

```
<styles>
    .clase-1 { ... }
    #identificador-1 { ... }
</styles>
<div class="clase-1">...</div>
<div id="identificador-1">...</div>
```

Aquí puedes conocer más sobre [Clases CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) e [Identificadores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

Debido a que Bootstrap es un framework, te sugiero que adaptes tu propio CSS con estas reglas mediante clases e identificadores.